# Is gravity with dual or multiple constants possible

Tags: java, android

I want to align a widget to the bottom-center of the screen. I am a using Frame Layout because I have a full screen app running behind the widget that I want to align. I set the parameters like this :

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Using the code above, the widget is aligned with the bottom of the screen but it is not centered. Is it possible to add a second constant to gravity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, use

```
Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM
```